# Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x-n\right)=\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

#### Background

My course notes (mathematics BSc, second-year module in real analysis, unpublished) have a proposition,

> Consider a sequence of functions $f_n:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Then the following statements are equivalent.
>
> - The sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$.
> - Let $M_n=\sup\{|f_n(t)-f(t)|\;|\;t\in[a,b]\}$. Then $M_n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$

The problem booklet has a question,

> For the following sequence of functions, determine the pointwise limit (if it exists) on the indicated interval, and decide whether $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to this limit.
> $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
> & 0 && x\leq n, \\ 
> & x-n && x\geq n,
> \end{cases}\hspace{2em}x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

The solution booklet has,

> Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then for any $n\geq x$, we have $f_n(x)=0$, so the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to the zero function.
>
> On the other hand, $$M_n=\sup\{|f_n(t)-0|\;|\;t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\infty,$$ so certainly $(M_n)$ does not converge to zero, and the sequence $(f_n)$ therefore does not converge uniformly to the zero function.

#### Question

Why does $M_n=\infty$? If both $x$ and $n$ are going to infinity, how do we know which one is larger?

Comment: For any fixed $n$, the value $t-n$ can be arbitrarily large, so $M_n=\infty$.

Comment: @runway44 Indeed; but should it be obvious that that remains true as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Yes. Do you think there's any value of $n$ for which $M_n$ is not $\infty$?

Comment: @runway44 No, but then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n$ is not a value of $n$.

Comment: Nobody is talking about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n$. If you agree that each of $M_1,M_2,M_3,\cdots$ is $\infty$ then you should agree that the claim $M_n\to0$ is false.

Comment: To answer your last question, "how do we know which is larger," when computing $M_n$ we assume $n$ is fixed while $x\to\infty$, so we know $x$ gets larger in the limit, by design.

Comment: @runway44 Aren't we talking about $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}M_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x-n\right)$?

Comment: Yes we are. And $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n$ is irrelevant to finding $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\big(\!\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(x-n)\big)$. When computing the inner limit, $n$ is fixed, so we are talking about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\infty$, which is $\infty$ in the extended real number system $[-\infty,\infty]$. Perhaps you are are getting $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n$ by splitting the double limit into a difference of double limits and simplifying the second term to a single limit, but that is not valid.

Comment: To elaborate, $\lim(a_n-b_n)=(\lim a_n)-(\lim b_n)$ is only valid when one or both of $\lim a_n$ or $\lim b_n$ is finite. In fact, your example is proof of that.

Comment: @runway44 That is what I'm thinking about, but I don't understand why this example proves the validity of that reasoning rather than begging it as a question. Is there some axiom or theorem that justifies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n-b_n)\neq(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n)-(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n)$ when one of the sequences is non-finite?

Comment: Well, what does $\infty-\infty$ even mean? The equality of the two sides can't be true if the right side is meaningless. (I suppose I should clarify $\infty-(-\infty)=+\infty$ and $(-\infty)-\infty=-\infty$ do make sense, though, so we can get away with both being infinite contrary to my previous comment, just not if they're the same sign.)

Comment: @runway44 Is the question "What does $\infty-\infty$ even mean?" difficult for reasons which don't apply similarly to the question, "What does $\infty$ even mean?"? We could define $\infty-\infty=0$, for instance, and I imagine (but don't know) that there are systems which do just that. This might be the sort of problem Cantor addressed, but I don't know enough about his work.

Comment: Yes. The difference $\infty-\infty$ cannot be defined in the extended number system in a way that makes $\lim(a_n-b_n)=(\lim a_n)-(\lim b_n)$ valid for positive infinite limits. For example, consider $(n+1)-n$ vs. $n-(n+1)$, or $n^2-n$ vs. $n-n^2$. All of these "split" to $\infty-\infty$ but they evaluate to different limits. So $\infty$ is just the name of an element of the extended real number system, and subtraction is a partial operation defined there, which cannot be extended to $\infty-\infty$ in a way that makes splitting limits universally valid.

Comment: @runway44 That's useful. I still feel a niggle about this, but I don't have any more clear objections for now. Thanks for your help. If you'd care to put any of this into an answer, I think you'll have earned the acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion means that *for each* $n$, $\sup\{|f_n(t)-0|\mid t\in\Bbb R\}=\infty$. But, for each fixed $n$,$$\lim_{t\to\infty}|f_n(t)-0|=\lim_{t\to\infty}t-n=\infty.$$